# How to read Power Query -> Web.Contents response header?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

```
let
    url = "http://XXXX/Account/Login",
    body = "{""UserName"": ""test""}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[          
     Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"],
     Content = Text.ToBinary(body) 
    ]))
in
    Source
```

How to read the Header value from Source?

Comment: I think this is not powerbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get response headers. You may get only request headers and some additional information. Use `Value.Metadata` function

```
let
    md = Value.Metadata(Web.Contents("https://www.google.com", [Headers=[qwer="asdf"], Query=[q="test"], IsRetry=true]))
in
    md
```

[image]

Comment: Combine that with `ManualStatusHandling` to get more information than errors show by default. <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents>